# Instrumenting Python 3.6 Lambda Function with X-Ray Causes Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6, aws-xray

I have a very simple Lambda function that I invoke with an IOT Button that runs an ECS Task, very light weight stuff. I had been interested in adding Tracing and found the "One-Click" tracing you get from Lambda does not give you a whole lot out of the box.

I have been reading through some posts about [Decorators](https://medium.com/@_kostya_/lambdas-in-python-integrated-with-x-ray-and-local-testing-a1f7d91c720d) and the [SDK Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python) as well as the AWS Docs on [Python tracing for Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-tracing.html) and thought it should be easy enough.

The beginning of my function is now as follows

```py
import boto3
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder

@xray_recorder.capture("handler")

def handler(event,context):
  client = boto3.client('ecs')
  response = client.run_task(
---python code---
  return str(response)
```

To which testing now gives me an error like such:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}

Request ID:
"REQID...e3f379f4702a"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: REQID...e3f379f4702a Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'aws_xray_sdk'
```

My Handler in the Console is simply `lambda_function.handler`, and worked before adding that instrumentation. I have done a few other varieties trying to use `Subsegments` instead within the code and run into the same issue. I am pretty novice when it comes to Python, so I am unsure where to check next, or if I am even doing this correctly.

If it's applicable, I had written the code in the console and don't use Layers or ZIP packaging either

Comment: What is the python filename? If your python filename was `lambda_function.py` then you would name it `lambda_function.handler` but if it was `lambda.py` then your handler would be named `lambda.handler` in this case. So in short the handler name should be `python-filename.function-name`

Comment: @d_kennetz my Python file name is `lambda_function.py` - so I think my Handler is setup correctly. I works fine without `from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder @xray_recorder.capture("handler")` in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong (a few things) but luckily for my ego, naming convention was not the wrong thing.

The aws-xray-sdk is an external dependency and needed to be built in versus doing it in the Console, I also went through packaging a few times and saw an `module missing` error for `Queue` which is included with the `multiprocessing` library from Python 3.x.

In a Cloud9 IDE I did the follow steps

```sh
mkdir package && cd package
pip install multiprocessing --system -t ./
pip3 install boto3 --system -t ./
pip install aws-xray-sdk --system -t ./
chmod -R 755 .
zip -r ../myDeploymentPackage.zip .
cd -
aws s3 cp myDeploymentPackage.zip s3://<my-bucket>/<my-path>/
```

In the Lambda console I specified the URL for the current Version of the uploaded Zip file, enabled X-Ray tracing in the Console and I got it working just fine. I also had to modify how I had my Python code written just slightly to take advantage of patching `boto3` as well as the automatic instrumentation, since the function is pretty simple and makes one or 2 calls to different services with Boto, it now looks like this:

```py
import boto3
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch

patch(['boto3'])

@xray_recorder.capture("handler")

def handler(event,context):
  client = boto3.client('<service here>')
```

Comment: Hi, at what stage did you add the function code? `package` was created so it is empty and the code isn't in it, on the other hand you zip content of `package` only. So how did you do it? Thanks!

Comment: `pip3 install multiprocessing --system -t ./` : no such option: --system. I am in Cloud9, of course.

Comment: A few things @putnik - I was on Ubuntu and also made sure Pip and Pip3 and associated Python/Python3 was installed. The lambda function file was in that directory too. Make sure it is there before you ZIP it.

Comment: @burningjenkinscontainer my lambda function is not able to find the aws_sdk module. My lamda function is in main folder and aws_sdk in libs folder (outside main folder). Do I need to update syspath?